# What does a readonly modifier for a method do?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, c#-7.0

I write this code

```cs
struct Test
{
    public override string ToString()
        => "some text";
}
```

Then I get a compiler message suggestion [IDE0251 Member can be made 'readonly'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0251)

this message is gone by applying `readonly` modifier as following

```cs
struct Test
{
    public override readonly string ToString()
        => "some text";
}
```

What this even mean?
I don't see such case listed in [readonly (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly#ref-readonly-return-example)

The closes case is with `ref` returns however the docs don't give me any clue what it means in above case.

Can any one state what a `readonly` here suppose to do?

Comment: It's right above where you linked to, Readonly instance members

Comment: It's not valid C# syntax. That shouldn't compile. Can you confirm you've posted code that does compile for you?

Comment: @harold Ah, ok. I've jumped to examples and assumed "Readonly instance members" would point that "ToString()" itself would be readonly  (like in readonly field) which doesn't make sense so I skipped that. My bad...

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes it's valid code

Comment: I see I'm not the only one confused. If the compiler is able to tell that a method can be readonly, it should mark it automatically...

Comment: @topsail no, it only means that the method will not mutate an instance(modify instance members)

Comment: @Pawulon - Missing information in this question - you're using a `struct`. The `readonly` is valid in a `struct`.,

Comment: @topsail Perfectly valid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly#readonly-instance-members Anyway, we don't *need* `readonly` here, it's only a recommendation. So the questions' premise is wrong.

Comment: @topsail Still, it was invalid code but just stripped off the the context. Who said the code inserts on SO have to be copy-paste-compliable? I didn't specify it was a class either. You just assumed a context where it is not valid. I also didn't made the "Can any one state why we need readonly here?" premise. I just asked "What is a difference?".  And I also wrote "I've applied proposed fix "Make member readonly"" which also indicated that change was made automatically by IDE so it should be a valid code...